# IBM Tivoli dsm.sys

Tags: ibm, tivoli

I am currently using TSM 5.5 ServerOnly for clients in DMZ.

When I run the backup with a test schedule it connects fine sending files to server in LAN however, the files/folders sent arent defined in dsm.sys.

My question is, besides dsm.sys, is there any other place TSM looks for configurations on a Linux box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with virtual mount points, ext4fs and the TSM client version.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Could you please mark this answer as the accepted answer for other people to benefit?

Comment: hey thx, sorry about the late-ness.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration Files at IBM Tivoli Backup Client :

> Deafult Directory: /opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/
>
> - dsm.sys
> - dsm.opt
>
> [IBM Tivoli backup client guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.bar.doc/barmst69.htm)

When I used TSM backup, all the configuration at the client (dsm.sys) will be override by the server. You may want to look at the file backup server for configuration, too.